# Redraw problems with X11 and cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, vmware, x11, redraw

I have the following constellation here:

- I have running a VMware Linux Ubuntu image (turnkey core).
- I am working with Windows 7, have installed Cygwin and the X-server there.
- I start an xterm on Linux.

When I do now work in that xterm window, I get a lot of redraw errors. Here are a few examples what I see. There seems to be at least to (independent?) problems:

- Small lines drawn when navigating in `vim`.
- No redraw of regions that are scrolled out or should be redrawn.

I have checked if these problems exist as well when using locally under X11 in Cygwin, but there, I don't have any problems. What should I check, and how to fix the redraw problems possibly?

---

Here are some screenshots  that illustrate what I am doing:

[image]

Everything is fine here, no problem at all.

[image]

Opening vim, showing the current directory, navigation there up and down

[image]

Navigating now with page up and down, no redraw of the right side (e.g. the term `TreeBookmarks` right from blue `bin/`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a X11 redraw error, but a problem with your terminal/encoding settings.. You've set some unicode locale, but the terminal is incapable of properly rendering unicode. Instead of xterm start uxterm (note the leading u).

You've listed the contents of a directory and I bet there's some file in that directory containing non-ASCII characters.
Another possible cause of the problem, that the TERM environment variable doesn't match the actually used terminal program, and things like colorization escape sequences mess it up.

You can make those mishappen letters go away by executing the `reset` program, which will return the terminal to its initial state.

But this is not a X11 problem.

Comment: Thank's a lot, i now managed to set it up correct. I have added the following info: I call `uxterm` instead of `xterm`; I set `LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8`; I added an appropriate [font for xterm in `.Xdefaults`](http://www.madboa.com/geek/utf8/).